# (Laravel 5.3) How to add new key and value to existing sub array in existing Collection?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3.

existing Collection $a is

```
$a = collect(
[
 0 =>[
      'firstName' => 'John',
      'lastName' => 'Doe'
     ],
1 =>[
     'firstName' => 'Mary',
     'lastName' => 'Jane'
    ]
]);
```

and desired result is as below:

```
$a = collect(
[
 0 => [
       'firstName' => 'John',
       'lastName' => 'Doe',
       'occupation' => 'engineer'
      ],
 1 => [
       'firstName' => 'Mary',
       'lastName' => 'Jane',
       'occupation' => 'accountant'
      ]
]);
```

I tried to test ->push(), ->put(), ->prepend() but no success. Please let me know the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`transform`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-transform) method which iterates over the collection and calls the given callback with each item in the collection. The items in the collection will be replaced by the values returned by the callback:

```
$a->transform(function ($item, $key) {
    $item['occupation'] = 'some_value';
    retrun $item;
});
```

Then check the value of `$a`:

```
dd($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have a collection of arrays, not a collection of collections. Hence, you can't use `push()`, `put()`, etc., in the sub-arrays.

The easiest way is probably just to treat it as an array:

```
$a[0]['occupation'] = 'engineer';
```

But you can also access at least the first element through the getter if you'd like:

```
$a->get(0)['occupation'] = 'engineer';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but 
When I tried "$a[0]['occupation'] = 'engineer';" I got a error as following:

$a[0]['occupation'] = 'engineer';

Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Support\Collection has no effect

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing collection then you can get all the arrays from it using something like this:

```
$items = $existingCollection->all();
```

Now, you have an array of arrays in `$items`. So you can add key/value using something like this:

```
$item[0]['occupation'] = 'engineer';
$item[1]['occupation'] = 'accountant';
```

Now, you've modified the arrays so if you want to turn it back into a collection then you can do it easily using this:

```
 $existingCollection = collect($items);
```

You could've also used `map` on the collection directly, for example:

```
$existingCollection->map(function ($person) {
    $person['occupation'] = 'engineer';
    return $person;
});
```

In this case, you can see that, all the person's occupation is going to be same but you can find out a way to make the difference but I can't give you more precise solution because I don't know much about your situation (You didn't share much).